# AsyncTask x MultiThreading

Tags: android, multithreading, async

Quando é mais vantajoso usar AsyncTask, e quando usar Threads.

Por exemplo:

Fazer download de algum arquivo(ex: JSON).

Qual seria mais vantajoso nesse caso e porque??

Comment: Afinal `Thread` ou `Service` ou `AsyncTask`? Não fiquei minimamente esclarecido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se for um simples¹ arquivo JSON, utilize **AsyncTask**.

**AsyncTask** é mais útil para operações assíncronas *(d'oh)* com baixa demanda de dados; por outro lado, todavia, as **Java Threads** são relevantes quando tratamos de alta demanda de dados, operações com a GUI e aplicativos que consomem muito hardware e que rodam em *background*.

Como boas referências, você pode ler [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) e [Threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) para Android.

*¹: pequeno, trivial, sem* muita *demanda.*

Comment: Não concordo com essa resposta. `AsyncTasks` usam `Threads` por debaixo dos panos, e ambas só devem ser usadas para operações de pouca duração (para operações mais longas, use `Services`). A vantagem da `AsyncTask` é simplificar operações assíncronas que devem acessar o thread de UI (isto é, atualizar a tela) antes, durante ou depois da operação em si, dispensando o uso de `Handlers` para efetuar essas atualizações (sem esses recursos, os Threads nem sequer acessam a GUI).

Comment: Na sua resposta, você citou `Service` e `AsyncTask` - no fim das contas, pelo uso da palavra *porém* por você usada, pra mim não fico claro qual é o seu melhor palpite. Enfim, como réplica, eu concordo que Threads rodam embaixo de AsyncTasks - a própria documentação fala isso - mas a questão é: no caso dele, melhor uma thread "pura" ou uma AsyncTask? Eu vou de AsyncTask - eis o foco da resposta para a pergunta em questão.

Comment: Para finalizar, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html, http://www.mergeconflict.net/2012/05/java-threads-vs-android-asynctask-which.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480206/asynctask-vs-thread-in-android e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797550/android-asynctask-for-long-running-operations. Portanto, baseado em tudo o que você falou, eu já não sei mais o que pensar.

Comment: Olhando os links acredito que você tem razão, `Threads` são viáveis para downloads mais demorados. Eu achei que `Services` teriam prioridade e durabilidade maiores no sistema, mas posso estar enganado. Vou refazer minha resposta. Só duas coisas: o _Vogella.com_ propõe tanto `Threads` como `Services` ([aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)) para fazer download, então não ajuda a esclarecer esse ponto; e o trecho _"operações com a GUI"_ precisa ser esclarecido, pois como falei threads que não sejam a thread de UI não são capazes de acessar a GUI.

Answer (score 6):

`AsyncTasks` usam `Threads` por debaixo dos panos, e servem para simplificar a exibição na tela do progresso da operação que está sendo feita em *background* (antes, durante ou depois de sua execução). Mas como `AsyncTasks` são fracamente vinculadas ao ciclo de vida da `Activity` e também podem causar memory leaks se forem mal implementadas, deve-se dar preferência a seu uso para operações muito curtas (no máximo alguns segundos).

Para operações mais longas pode-se usar `Threads` ou `Services` (no primeiro caso exibir o resultado na tela envolve o uso de um `Handler`, e no segundo o uso de um `BroadcastReceiver`).

Para download de arquivos portanto use `Thread` ou `Service`. Porém, para receber o retorno de uma requisição a um webservice (o caso JSON que você citou) em que a quantidade de dados recebida é pequena e esses dados precisam ser exibidos na tela, é mais simples usar `AsyncTask`.